# Delete key appears to remove two characters

Tags: neovim

I open a simple HTML file and navigate to a section of the file where I want to delete a character. I enter INSERT mode and press the DEL key, this *seemingly* causes two characters to be removed, however, if I save the file and view it I can see that only one character was removed (correct behavior).

If I repeat this process and ESC into NORMAL mode and then press CTRL+SHIFT+L after the DEL key, neovim redraws and the missing character reappears. What could be causing this issue?

Before pressing DEL key:
[image]

After pressing DEL key:
[image]

After ESCaping into NORMAL mode and pressing CTRL+SHIFT+L:
[image]

Comment: might be a terminal issue. Does it happen, if you start `vim --clean`?  What terminal are you using?

Comment: Check the output of `verbose imap <bs>` if you can't repro with a clean vim

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt the issue occurs despite opening file file using `nvim --clean`. I'm using windows terminal (the new one), I've tried with nvim on windows and linux via WSL and I see the same behaviour.

@Zoe the output of `:verbose imap <bs>` was `no mapping found`.

(I've also checked and the font is monospaced and it occurs even with a different font)

Comment: @HennyH and everything latest version? File a bug at the neovim repository then. BTW: you should check `:verbose imap <del>` , because the issue is with the del key and not backspace if I understand correctly.

Comment: Associated GitHub issue: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/15020

Comment: Feels like an emoji handling issue. I can't reproduce in terminal or GUI vim or neovim on Linux, and good 'ol ⚠️ is an ambiguous width character.

Comment: Well if this is a reported issue, dare I say a bug, this is not something we can answer here, can we?